# Accessing fetched data in React Native without using React State

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have a typescript function that is responsible for fetching data from the NASA api using the React Native fetch function and returning a custom object that has type Item[]. The issue is that the returned object from this function is always [].
The responseData.collection.items worked when originally setting a state variable of type Item[] to it so it is not a mapping issue.

However, I would like this to be a separate typescript function outside of any React components so I cannot use state.

What is the correct way of accessing the fetched JSON response data in typescript without using React Native state?

```
import { Item } from "../types/data"

export function fetchData(searchTerm: string): Item[] {
let result: Item[] = []
fetch(`https://images-api.nasa.gov/search? q=${searchTerm}&media_type=image`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
              result = responseData.collection.items
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
            })
            return result
 }
```

Comment: and what are you planning to do with that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an async function:

```js
import { Item } from "../types/data"

export async function fetchData(searchTerm: string): Promise<Item[]> {
  
  const response = await fetch(`https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=${searchTerm}&media_type=image`)
  const responseResult = await response.json()
  return result.collection.items as Item[]
 
 }
```

Now the function returns a promise, so wherever you need the data:

```js
import { fetchData } from './path/to/file.ts'

fetchData(searchTerm)
   .then((items: Item[]) => {
      // Here you have access to your items and you can do whatever you need with them
   })
   .catch(err => console.warn(err)
```